# Android JUnit test - how to mock google api call

Tags: android, junit, in-app-billing

I'm learning JUNIT tests and wanted to create a test for purchases.
I do not understand how can I not "fake" generate result of google API function `querySkuDetailsAsync` which returns `responseCode` and list of `skuDetails` which I then pass to `calculatePrice()` for instance. How do I get these results in test function?.

```
fun getPriceAndProductId(
        obj: Object,
        listener: (price: Double, productId: String) -> Unit
) {
     val skus = listOf(
            sku1,
            sku2,
            sku3)

     billingManager.querySkuDetailsAsync(
            BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP,
            skus,
            SkuDetailsResponseListener { responseCode, skuDetailsList ->
                if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    val price = calculatePrice(...)
                    val productId = calculateProductId(...)

                } else {
                    LogUtil.debug("...", "Unable to get SKUS: $responseCode")
                }
            })
}
```

JUnit:

```
@Test
fun testProductPrice() {
    val skuDetailsList = /* somehow call google API and get the skus */
    assertEquals(objectClass.calculatePrice(skuDetailsList), "0.0")
}
```

Comment: Still looking for answer. :/